# function not found onPress react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a button in my react-native which I'm using the `onPress` callback variable on. For some reason I get an error saying that the function can't be found.

I have the code below as follows:

```js
tranfer = () => {
    console.log("transferring");
    this.props.navigation.navigate('TransferScreen');
  }

  render() {
    var sections = [
      //Info.
    ];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <ScrollView>
          <SectionList
            style={styles.container}
            renderItem={this._renderItem}
            renderSectionHeader={this._renderSectionHeader}
            stickySectionHeadersEnabled={true}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
            ListHeaderComponent={this._renderListHeader}
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            sections={sections}
          />
          </ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.footer}>
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                  <Icon.Button backgroundColor="#29a329" onPress={()=>this.transfer()}>
                    <Text style={{color: "white"}}>Transfer</Text>
                  </Icon.Button>
                </View>
          </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Weirdly, I copied and pasted this from another screen where it is working! So I'm not sure what could be going on here. I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have **typo**

you named your function `tranfer` and in ***onPress*** you call `this.transfer()` so just edit your function name to

```
transfer = () => {
    console.log("transferring");
    this.props.navigation.navigate('TransferScreen');
  }
```

Comment: mistakes happens :)